# When uploading a file, these two lines of code appear to do the same thing but only one of them works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried writing the two following lines in my View to upload a file.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

­

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Attachments", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Both lines of code `POST` to the `Create` action on the `Attachments` controller, shown by both lines hitting a break point I set up inside of `Create`. However, only the second line correctly uploads the attachment. The first line has the attachment set to `null`.

Why doesn't the first line upload the file, even though it also appears to be performing a `POST` on `Create` in `Attachments`?

---

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Attachment</h4>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", name = "file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AttachmentID,AttachmentName")] Attachment attachment, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(attachment);
}
```

Comment: If you look at the two method overloads you will see that they are NOT doing the same thing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to upload a file, the `<form>` element needs a `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute.

You first attempt is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.Object%29) which is adding a route value, and assuming the GET method is the `Create()` method of `AttachmentsController`, you are generating

```
<form action="/Attachments/Create?enctype=multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

and there is no `enctype` attribute, therefore the `HttpPostedFileBase file` parameter is `null`.

The second attempt is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29) where the 4th argument is the `htmlAttributes` and generates

```
<form action="/Attachments/Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see how I used the overloading incorrectly. Also, did you mean to write 'assuming the **POST** method'?

Comment: No, I meant the GET method - in the 1st example, the `action` attribute will be the url of the GET method if you do not specify a controller and action name (as per the 2nd example)

Comment: On `Create`, `[HttpPost]` is [an attribute that is used to restrict an action method so that the method handles only HTTP POST requests.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: You misunderstood my comment - I know what `[HttpPost]` is :). When you use `@using( Html.BeginForm())` - i.e without using one of the overloads that specify the action and/or controller name (or is you used `using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` ) the method generates the `action` attribute based on the GET method url (and adds route or query string values as required)